# How to crop a 3D model on paint3D?

Tags: paint-3d

Is there a way to crop 3D on paint 3D? If there's not, is there other friendly software to do it and then import it to paint 3D?

Comment: Cropping only makes sense if you have a 2d image what would 3d cropping look like?

Comment: I'm similarly confused like @joojaa A 3D model can't be cropped like an image. Do you perhaps want to crop a rendered image? Then export as PNG and crop in raster software.

Comment: 3D cropping with hardware has been and it still is in wide use. Some devices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillotine. Doing it in 3D design software needs a program which allows either boolean subtract or dividing a solid piece with a surface. CAD and many artistic 3D modelling programs have them. Unfortunately just what's in paint 3D isn't widely known here, because most of us draw, make layouts and mangle 2D images. Search for boolean operations and division.

Comment: @user287001 but that is cutting. Even so you need to define how to cut. Box sides ony 4 sides or what. Or crop the final image. So cropping is clearly defined in 2D but in 3D its hard to know where and how to crop.